# Toshiba Satellite L755 - Key for BIOS settings?

Tags: bios, toshiba-laptop

I'm trying to get into my Toshiba laptop's bios so I can boot from USB to install Xubuntu, but the POST is darting by too fast for me to try different keys, and the first thing I see on my screen when booting is the Windows logo. I don't even see Toshiba's logo anymore.

Does anyone know the correct key to access the BIOS on a Toshiba Satellite L755 series? Exact model is L755-S5246.

Comment: I have to issue a downvote because of the lack of research on your part I discovered this thread http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Computer-Troubleshooting/3-10-BIOS-Update-for-Satellite-Pro/td-p/285057 from the following google search https://www.google.com/#q=Toshiba+Satellite+L755++Bios+key&fp=69196bdaa6ab1382&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all the options on forums and the Toshiba site, I went through all the f keys a couple of times and found f12 worked the second time around. Try ctrl+alt+delete to reset to Toshiba screen quickly when one doesn't work and it begins to load os or go to blank screen. To load ubuntu I had to disable safe boot to change bios to old version, non uefi called csg or something. Boot worked fine for linux after that. Alternatively, if you still have windows 8 installed, go to start menu type bios in search bar, click on change advanced settings(think it was called, the first obvious option anyway) and you can do it through the interface provided.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need to access BIOS on your Toshiba laptop - Press and hold the f2 button as soon as it is restarted or turned on.

P.S - The reason *why* you do not see your BIOS screen is because of a quick boot. You should be able to find the option for something like *boot speed* in the advanced menu within the BIOS and if you change it to normal and save the settings then it should be fine.

Cheers !!

Comment: I was able to get in with F12 shortly after posting the question. And yeah, it was set to quick boot, which is a little odd because I don't remember setting that. Oh well. Now I get to begin my transition into a Linux user!

Comment: @Akai Glad that you're in the next step now. By the way the issue that you experienced with regards to quick boot would possibly be due to an automatic BIOS update if you have not changed the setting manually. Please *care* to mark your question as answered if you consider this issue to be resolved. Thanks.

Comment: so if I have quick boot, then to get into bios, I will first have to get into bios, and turn of quick boot.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give an FYI on the L75D-A7280 Windows 8.1 Laptop, i had some similar issues where the laptop would not boot into windows 8, because the MBR was corrupt and i couldnt boot into the recovery partition either, so my quick and dirty workaround since i didnt have any install media was to install ubuntu next to windows 8 (made a free 8gb partition in the big NTFS partition), then let grub-install and perform the heavy lifting of the MBR.

- f12 into bios
- setup (bios) go and change from UEFI to CRM
- boot boot into ubuntu make a small 8gb partition install ubuntu / grub
- change default boot order in grub to boot windows 8 first https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader

  - set timeout to 1